# FFT processing of audio sample

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft

I am novice in audio processing with mathematical background so I have few (a lot, but few for starters) questions about processing extracted samples with fft.

I am using fft implementation from http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-simple-and-efficient-fft-implementatio/199702312?pgno=1 with fixed array length.

I have some set of samples (lets say 1024 samples in set).

Fft algorithm which takes input complex values (real and imaginary), imaginary values are set to 0, because I don't have any and stripping fft output of it's imaginary part.

I have next questions:

1) Is my assumption that samples are real numbers correct?

2) Is there efficient implementation of FFT which work only on real 
numbers? I mean there is no imaginary part at all in calculations.

3) If I continue using described process, is it correct assumption that if there is no imaginary data in input of fft (all zeros), imaginary part of fft output will be also zero for all values?

PS I am sorry if question already exist but I didn't find any satisfying answer on my questions.

Comment: Even for purely real input, the output will (usually) have an imaginary component.  The absolute value (magnitude) of the output represents the power of the corresponding frequency, and the argument (angle between the complex value and the real axis) represents the phase for that frequency.  For audio applications, often phase is ignored and just the magnitude is retained, but the imaginary component will still contribute to this and cannot be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what impact I can have if ignore imaginary part? I am trying to do analysis of audio to create similarity measure. I dont really understand how to implement statistical measures, do I calculate measures on real then on imaginary part, and how to merge those two measures in one?

Comment: If you ignore the imaginary part then your output will be completely screwed up. What you should do is take the absolute value of each output - that is sqrt(real\*real + imag\*imag)

Comment: Yeah, what immibis said is probably what you want.  Separately, the real and imaginary parts don't correspond to features one would want to measure in an audio waveform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is my assumption that samples are real numbers correct?

Yes.

> 2) Is there efficient implementation of FFT which work only on real numbers? I mean there is no imaginary part at all in calculations.

If there was, it would still need to use imaginary numbers in the calculations. (Sure, it could do complex math with pairs of real numbers, and just label the second number something that isn't "imaginary", but what advantage would that have?)

> 3) If I continue using described process, is it correct assumption that if there is no imaginary data in input of fft (all zeros), imaginary part of fft output will be also zero for all values?

This is not correct.

The absolute value of each number in the FFT output is proportional to the amplitude of each frequency in the signal.

The *phase* of each frequency in the signal is also encoded in the output, as the [*argument*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29) of the complex numbers. That is, if some frequency is 90 degrees out-of-phase with a sine wave, the argument of that bin will be 90 degrees - that is, the real part will be 0 and the imaginary part will have the amplitude! And for phases that aren't multiples of 90 degrees, both the real and imaginary parts will be nonzero.

If you don't care about phase information, you can take the absolute value of each output number - that is, `sqrt(real*real + imag*imag)`.